# How to setup a virtual host which points to a different port and context path?

Tags: tomcat, war, virtualhost

I'm working on a JSF 2.0 project and I have it on an Apache Tomcat 7.0.5 Server as a .war file. I've deployed it and I can view it at http://localhost:9080/exampleApp1.

I recently purchased a domain name. so I've set up a virtual host in my server so that when someOne goes into www.theDomainIBought.com it goes to my server and I have a little html file that says under construction.

what I want to do is Whenever someone goes into www.theDomainIBought.com I want them to open up the exampleApp1. What is the best(easiest) way to do this? I was told to set up a virtual host but all the examples I found says they'd need to type in www.theDomainIBought.com:9080/exampleApp1 Which is NOT what I want, I want them to just put in the domain (www.theDomainIBought.com) and it'll open up the app. how can I achieve this?

I have two apaches, one that came with wamp server and the onw I deploy my app in.
this is what I have in my wamp/apache httpd.conf file for the hosting right now:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\domainIBought"
ServerName www.domainIBought.com
ServerAlias domainIBought.com
</VirtualHost>
```

but it won't let me put VirtualHost *:9080/exampleApp1

Answer (score -1):

You need to configure mod_jk for redirect the traffic from Apache to Tomcat. check the following documentation:

http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html

Comment: wow all that? one would think this comes up so often that there'd be an easier way. i though it would have something to do with the "host manager" in tomcat, they have a gui, is that for something else then ?